# How to create a warning message in Excel when must-field is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table where column F is Name and column H is Age.
When F9 is filled, I want H9 to become automatically a must-field.

If I filled in cell F9 and did not fill in cell H9, a message is displayed: "please fill in age!". Only when I filled H9, I can proceed and write something else. The same happens for F10-H10, F11-H11...

If F9 is empty, nothing happens.

Comment: You could do this by adding two input-boxes for each with a MsgBox in case the age cell is not filled.

Comment: How do you want to check this? Do you want a button to click to check this?

Comment: Thank you, the user is then still able to fill in everything manually and will then not use the provided button. I need something that doesn't allow him to write in F9 without also writing in H9.

Comment: What is a must-field ? What happens if must-fields are not filled ?

Comment: It is a field that must be filled in order to be able to save the document.

Comment: Or in order to be able to write something else in another field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy formula approach:
 in H9 enter

```
=IF(F9="","","please fill in age!")
```

The user would then overwrite the formula

As vba: put in the worksheet that the fields are in

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim name As Range
Dim age As Range
Dim i As Double
Dim lastrow As Double

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 9 To lastrow
    Set name = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & i)
    Set age = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i)
    If name.Value <> "" And age.Value = "" Then
       MsgBox "please fill in age!"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the Problem is he can still ignore the message. I need the field to be a must-field.

Comment: only with a userForm. that way u can control what u are saving to the sheet. if everything isnt ok, u dont allow the user to save

Comment: provided a vba approach as well

Comment: Thank you very much!! I did it eventually with a combination of Input Box and MsgBox. You helped me a lot! :)